# vba excel to put data in incremental way in specified column

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets WsRaw and WsFinal, WsRaw is source and WsFinal is result.
Sheet WsRaw has "Student" in ("B1") and their names in ("B2":B12") so total 10 names.
What I am trying to do is copying 1st name from WsRaw and pasting to WsFinal in 70rows Starting from ("B2").
And then copy 2nd name from WsRaw and paste them after the 70th name in WsFinal.

My code is able to copy and paste just first name, pls help to create a loop to pick all names and pasing them 70 times each.

Thanks

```
Sub UpdateRows()

    Dim Cel As Range, V As String
    
    
    Dim WsRaw, WsFinal As Worksheet
    Dim Raw_FC, Raw_LC, Final_FR, Final_LR, i, x, a As Long
    
    Dim r As Range
    Dim c As Range
    
    Dim rFirst As Range, rLast As Range
      
    Set WsRaw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw")
    Set WsFinal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final")
    
    Final_FR = WsFinal.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Final_LR = WsFinal.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(70).Row
    
   
    
    
With WsFinal


            For Each Cel In WsFinal.Range("B2:B" & Final_LR)
            On Error Resume Next
            V = WsRaw.Range("B2")
            Cel.Offset(0, 0) = V
            
            Next Cel

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Range.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Resize)

Update - added column C

```vb
Sub UpdateRows2()

    Const NO_ROWS = 70

    Dim wb As Workbook, WsRaw As Worksheet, WsFinal As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iFinal As Long, r As Long
    Dim iLastCol As Long, iCol As Long, rng As Range
  
        
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set WsFinal = wb.Worksheets("Final")
    Set WsRaw = wb.Worksheets("Raw")
    
    iLastRow = WsRaw.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    iLastCol = WsRaw.Cells(1, WsRaw.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    iCol = iLastCol - NO_ROWS + 1
    iFinal = 2
    For r = 2 To iLastRow
       
        WsFinal.Cells(iFinal, "B").Resize(NO_ROWS) = WsRaw.Cells(r, "B")

        Set rng = WsRaw.Cells(r, iCol).Resize(1, NO_ROWS)
        rng.Copy
        WsFinal.Cells(iFinal, "C").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        With WsFinal.Sort
            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom '/
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin '/
            .Apply
         End With

        iFinal = iFinal + NO_ROWS
    Next
    MsgBox iFinal - 2 & " rows copied to " & WsFinal.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry just realized I should have provided whole program.
added some code which is copying horizontal data and pasting vertically in final sheet.
working fine but pasting for first 70 rows only.
whereas I need it to be repeated till the end of last row of WsFinal("B")

Comment: the data in C2:C72 is basically dates in reverse order. and need to be pasted for every name

Comment: Avi `C2:C72` is 71 rows. Is that on wsFinal ? . Where is that data coming from ?

Comment: on WsFinal C2:C71 actually the data has been copied from WsRaw as mentioned in added codes

Comment: @avi What range on `wsRaw`  has been copied into `wsFinal.Range("C2:C71")` ? is is columns C to BT ?

Comment: Sorry to let you have trouble, just checked my edit to codes is pending and still you are trying, thanks
Dim rFirst, rLast As Range
    Set rLast = WsRaw.Cells(1, WsRaw.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 0)
    Set rFirst = rLast.Offset(0, -69)
Call Range(rFirst, rLast).Copy
        WsFinal.Range("C2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        
        With WsFinal.Sort
        .SetRange Range("C2:C71")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom '/
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin '/
        .Apply

Comment: my data is progressive actually so cant copy by specific columns name,
1 column is added on daily bases as new date.
so i have copied using offset method.
copied 1st row from last used column and towards left to 69 columns from WsRaw

Comment: Hi, 
I managed to make it work but, surprisingly your codes took 0.5 sec to copy around 65000 rows and with added same amount of data to adjacent column mine taking 40 secs and 25 secs with screenupdate set to false .
I think I am going through long way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub UpdateRows()
    Const times = 70
    Dim pos As Range, cl As Range
    
    Set pos = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WsFinal").Range("B2")
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WsRaw")
        For Each cl In .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            pos.Resize(times) = cl
            Set pos = pos.Offset(times)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```